# WPF VB.net: How can I filter a DataGrid and still use ObservableCollection functionality?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, observablecollection

I am using a customized `ObservableCollection` class.  I tagged on functionality so when an item is removed from the class, it automatically saves the new collection to a `.csv`.  If I can get this to work with the UI (`DataGrid`), I can save the .`csv` in real time any time any relevant changes are made to the collection.

```
    Class SourceTechDaysOff
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of Tech.DayOff)
    Private CSVPath As String

    Sub New(Optional CSVPath_ As String = Nothing)
        CSVPath = CSVPath_
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RemoveItem(index As Integer)
        MyBase.RemoveItem(index)
        If SuppressSave = False Then
            If CSVPath IsNot Nothing Then
                Using sw As New StreamWriter(CSVPath)
                    Using csv As New CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sw)
                        csv.WriteRecords(LstAllDaysOff)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

My problem is in the `DataGrid`.  I need to filter it to show only the records for a particular tech, which is selected in a separate list box.  So when I bind the collection instance (`LSTAllTechDaysOff`) I thought using Linq to filter the collection and still populate the `datagrid with the actual objects from the collection.  It actually DOES do that, I believe, but when I filter it in this way, I cannot delete the item from the list, therefore I cannot update the collection.  So I'm stuck.  (I apologize for the way the LINQ is formatted below. I was unsure how to get it to line up correctly, so you have to scroll over)

```
    Sub UpdateSelectedTechDataGrid(T As Tech)
    If T Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    T.DaysOff.Clear()
    For Each D In LstAllDaysOff
        If D.TechID = T.ID Then
            T.DaysOff.Add(D)
            '     MANUAL ADD - DOESN'T WORK
            'SelectedTechDaysOff_DataGrid.Items.Add(D)
        End If
    Next

    LstSelectedTechDaysOff.Clear()
    If T.DaysOff IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each D In T.DaysOff
            LstSelectedTechDaysOff.Add(D)
        Next
    Else

    End If
    '    SIMPLE LINQ QUERY - DOESN'T WORK
    'SelectedTechDaysOff_DataGrid.DataContext = From d In LstAllDaysOff
    '                                                                                    Where d.TechID = T.ID
    '                                                                                    Select d
    '    LINQ FUNCTION - DOESN'T WORK
    'SelectedTechDaysOff_DataGrid.DataContext = LstAllDaysOff.Where(Function(D)
    '                                                                                                                                If D.TechID = T.ID Then Return True
    '                                                                                                                                Return False
    '                                                                                                                            End Function)
    '   THIS IS UNFILTERED AND WORKS, BUT I NEED IT FILTERED.
    SelectedTechDaysOff_DataGrid.DataContext = LstAllDaysOff
    AllDaysOff.DataContext = LstAllDaysOff

End Sub
```

I also tried iterating through the collection and adding the items one by one if Tech.ID matches the ID I'm trying to view.  That works to filter the list but it seems to separate the items from the `ObservableCollection`, so it doesn't trigger the `RemoveItem` method.

I also wonder if there is a way to filter the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` after it's bound.

```
                    <DataGrid Name="SelectedTechDaysOff_DataGrid"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                                        <!--IS THERE A WAY TO FILTER ITEMSSOURCE AFTER IT IS BOUND-->             Margin="5"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                        CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                          CanUserAddRows="False">
```

So, to rephrase the question; What do I need to do to get the Items in the `DataGrid` filtered by TechID and still have them accessible by the `ObservableCollection`?

Thank You!

Comment: Apparently my question either was was really good or it really sucked, because no one replied.  Haha.  I've aborted the idea of filtering the list and holding onto observablecollection functionality.  Instead, I added a 2nd observable collection class that will house the 'selected tech' and communicate changes with the original that holds all records.  It sounds a bit clunky, but it will allow me to eliminate a lot of code in the main operation of the program.

Comment: If you are using a CSV, you don't go back the the collection itself to filter. Rather the CSV provides filtering for you automatically leaving it's source (your collection) unchanged.  This is very powerful because you can easily reset the view by clearing the CVS filter.  It also allows the user to select any thing else they want to see and automatically filters the base collection based on any new criteria.  So in a sense the CSV already has built in ability that doesn't require linq..

Comment: I learned a lot about filtering from this [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442498/Multi-filtered-WPF-DataGrid-with-MVVM]. I downloaded the code and stepped thru it with a debugger.